# Is it OK to return lua_integer type instead of lightuserdata in Lua when returning a C pointer?

Tags: c, lua

My C library returns a C pointer to lua environment, and I need to do some simple operations based on the value of that C pointer, just like:

```
my_pointer = c_pointer + 4
```

Since I can do nothing with lightuserdata so I am wondering if that is all right to return a lua_integer type for C pointer, instead of lightuserdata, so that I can do the simple manipulation based on the value of C pointer

Comment: I cannot imagine what circumstances would possess you to expose a *pointer* directly to Lua as a numeric value. Please don't do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll ignore the fact that `c_pointer + 4` is not a "simple operation", due to the fact that C++ uses pointer arithmetic. So the result of that expression would vary depending on what type `c_pointer` is.

I'll assume that you want to expose the pointer as a *number* to Lua, which it can do numerical arithmetic to. Then you'll convert it back to a pointer at some point.

This will work... so long as you're only compiling for 32-bit machines. In 64-bit compiles, pointers will be 64-bits in size. So you can't convert them into `double`s and back without loss of data.

Furthermore, you're likely to run into basic type trouble. If you expose a pointer as an integer, then presumably you've also exposed some function to Lua that *takes* this pointer-as-an-integer. Which means that the Lua program can shove *any number* at that function, which it will dutifully pretend is a pointer.

That's bad.

The correct way to do this is to not expose a pointer to Lua at all. If you need Lua to do math operations on a "pointer", expose a *full* userdata type that represents a pointer. But it should store the original pointer and an offset in its userdata. Overload the arithmetic operations on it, so that the user can add numbers to it and so forth. The user's additions and such should affect the offset, not the pointer. Or expose a dedicated memory buffer object, rather than a pointer.

Alternatively, expose the pointer as an opaque value, then have all of your APIs take an opaque pointer + an offset as a Lua number.

In short, *don't expose pointers to Lua.*

Comment: This is not really true.  A double can hold any integer from -2^53 to +2^53, more if it is a multiple of a power of two, e.g. multiples of 4 up to 2^55.  On all 64-bit platforms I am aware of, pointers are all inside this range (even with ASLR enabled), so you can convert them to and from doubles just fine.  There are good reasons to avoid exposing pointers to Lua, but this is not one of them.

Comment: "*A double can hold any integer from -2^53 to +2^53, more if it is a multiple of a power of two, e.g. multiples of 4 up to 2^55.*" I don't know how you get that last part. Especially since he wants to be able to add arbitrary numbers to such pointers, so even if that worked, it wouldn't work for the general case he's asking about.

Comment: @finnw: You would also need to *explicitly* convert such numbers, depending on the exact implementation of virtual memory addresses for the CPU in question. For example, on some x86-64 implementations, it does sign extension on bit 48, so a virtual memory pointer with bit 48 set will have all of the higher bits as 1, while others will have them as 0. You can't just cast such a number to a double and expect to get the same value back. You need *detailed* knowledge of the specific CPU you're using or else everything could break.

Comment: Both ranges (0xffffXXXXXXXXXXXX, sign extended and 0x0001XXXXXXXXXXXX, unsigned) will be preserved when converting to/from double.

Comment: @finnw: But only if you convert it via a *signed* cast rather than an unsigned cast (you must cast from/to a signed 64-bit integer). And you would only know to do that if you *assume* the construction of a particular pointer. Which goes back to my main point: you need *detailed knowledge* of the specific CPU or else everything could break.

Comment: I don't think this is an issue unless you know of a 64-bit arch/OS combination where uint64_t<->double conversion is lossy.  Certainly there are ARM64 devices where 0x5555000000010000 is a valid pointer, but AFAIK no OS that will allocate virtual addresses in this range.  I have even seen pointer arithmetic on 4D arrays using doubles for intermediate values with a mix of positive/negative indices, which works fine on x86-64 and ARM64 with base addresses up to 2^47.  I don't think this is worth worrying about until at actually arises (at which point you are porting to a new platform anyway)

Comment: @finnw: Why would you use a method that has pitfalls (no matter how remote or unlikely they are today) if another method can be used which has the same effect but *doesn't* have those pitfalls? That way, when "you are porting to a new platform", you don't have broken code. Cross-platform code should be cross-platform, not sorta-kinda-maybe cross-platform except when it isn't.

Comment: I don't think "cross platform" includes platforms that have not been invented yet.  Also your proposal is equally unsafe (because you still compute offsets in Lua.)

Comment: @finnw: "*I don't think "cross platform" includes platforms that have not been invented yet.*" In the most general sense, it does. There's C and C++ code that works perfectly fine on platforms that didn't exist when they were written. Again, considering that you gain *nothing* by opening yourself up to this potential problem, there's no reason to do so.

Comment: @finnw: "*Also your proposal is equally unsafe (because you still compute offsets in Lua.)*" Assuming you're talking about my second suggestion (the first one does all of the offsetting internally, so you have whatever precision you want), it's not "*equally*" unsafe, because you would only encounter a problem when the *offset* exceeds the maximum size of an integer stored in a double. A change in platform will not cause this; it's caused *entirely* by your code. And therefore, you can write code that would never trigger it no matter the platform.